# How to apply secondary value to an input element

Tags: forms, input, placeholder

I have some input elements in my contact form, I want to display "title, name, email etc. as placeholder but not as label. However their placeholders are already occupied by another php tags, how could I display my custom placeholders after all inside these inputs?

```
    <p><!--EMAIL-->
    <label for="postEmail"><?php _e('your mail', 'themolitor') ?><span class="red">*</span></label><?php if ($postEmailError != '') { ?> <span class="error"><?php echo $postEmailError; ?></span><?php } ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="formExample">- <?php _e('will not publish','themolitor');?></span><br />
 <input type="email" name="postEmail" id="postEmail" class="required" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['postEmail']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST"){ echo $_POST['postEmail']; } ?>" /><br />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the input's value is set by PHP not the placeholder. So if you want to append a string to an input's value -- use the `+=` operator. In the demo the text is small so you don't have to scroll.

```js
document.getElementById('postEmail').value += 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 3;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="postEmail" id="postEmail" class="required" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['postEmail']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != ' POST '){ echo $_POST['postEmail']; } ?>">
```

Comment: I didn't not exactly understand what should I do, I managed to add value but it appears only when window loads

<script>
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("postEmail").value += "value";
}
</script>

What I want to create actually onblur effect like real placeholder

or like following

onblur='if (this.value == &quot;&quot;) {this.value = &quot;your mail...&quot;;}' onfocus='if (this.value == &quot;your mail...&quot;) {this.value = &quot;&quot;;}' type='text' value='your mail..'